# How do I effectively get on top of a platform that I am swinging from under with a grappling hook?

Tags: trine-2

In this screenshot, I am trying to get the experience orb on top of this wooden platform that I am swinging from under with a grappling hook - what are effective methods to do this?

[image]

When I try to do this, it's a hit or miss. Are there effective methods? (Like how many number of swings before an attempt, recommended distance from the platform when swinging, when to press or release which buttons, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a tricky jump, but I pretty consistently succeed in making it.

1. Start with a medium-to-long rope length, when you're at one extreme of the swing.
2. As you swing to the other side, shorten the rope until you're close to the platform - but not too close. In your screenshot above, a good distance will be equal to about half that platform's width.
3. Let go of the rope at around 80° angle - i.e. just a little bit before the rope becomes horizontal.
4. Keep the movement key pressed while in-air to try to land on it. Be careful, with narrow platforms it's also easy to overshoot them, not just fall short of them.

The number of swings before doing the attempt doesn't have any effect.