# How to get on top of a platform with a thief's grappling hook?

Tags: trine-3

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60296/how-do-i-effectively-get-on-top-of-a-platform-that-i-am-swinging-from-under-with) answers for Trine 2. I'm trying Trine 3 now and I can't pull this off. Is it still possible in Trine 3? If yes, how?